# How can I cut four numbers after the decimal number without rounding using MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, rounding

I have a number like this:

**2.32166873546944**

I want to take only four numbers after the decimal point and **without rounding**, that is, I only want:

**2.3216**

How do I do this in **Matlab** ?

I tried several times to get the desired result but I was unable to do so. Please help me....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using `round`

From the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/round.html) (emphasis added),

> `Y = round(X)` rounds each element of `X` to the **nearest integer**. In the case of a **tie**, where an element has a fractional part of `0.5` (within roundoff error) in decimal, the `round`  function rounds **away from zero** to the nearest integer with larger magnitude.

Thus, truncating to `n` decimal figures can be achieved by reducing the absolute value of the number by `0.5*10^-n` and then applying `round`:

```
n = 4;
x = 2.32166873546944;
y = round(x-sign(x)*0.5*10^-n, n);
```

### Using `fix`

From the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fix.html) (emphasis added),

> `Y = fix(X)` rounds each element of X to the **nearest integer toward zero**.

Thus, it suffices to multiply by `10^n`, apply `fix`, and then divide by `10^n`:

```
n = 4;
x = 2.32166873546944;
y = fix(x*10^n)/10^n;
```